# Getting Error while trying to install liferea RSS Reader

Tags: unity, synaptic, dependencies

Once  I Press install I get:

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

Details
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

liferea: Depends: libatk1.0-0 (>= 1.12.4) but 2.0.0-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but 2.13-0ubuntu13 is to be installed
         Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.8.0) but 2.8.0-2.1ubuntu3 is to be installed
         Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.4.4-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
         Depends: libgconf2-4 (>= 2.31.1) but 2.32.2-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
         Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but 2.23.3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: libglade2-0 (>= 1:2.6.1) but 1:2.6.4-1build1 is to be installed
         Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0) but 2.28.6-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.18.0) but 2.24.4-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
         Depends: libice6 (>= 1:1.0.0) but 2:1.0.7-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: libnotify1-gtk2.10 but it is a virtual package
         Depends: libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) but 1.28.4-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: libsoup2.4-1 (>= 2.26.1) but 2.34.0-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.7.3) but 3.7.4-2ubuntu5 is to be installed
         Depends: libunity4 (>= 3.4.6) but 3.8.4-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: libxml2 (>= 2.7.4) but 2.7.8.dfsg-2ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
         Depends: gconf2 (>= 2.28.1-2) but 2.32.2-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
         Depends: liferea-data (= 1.6.4-1ubuntu7) but 1.6.5-1~mmwkt1 is to be installed
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see this was a temporary glitch in the package system - so it should be fine now.

Update your computer (as is outlined in this question: [How do I update Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56348/how-do-i-update-ubuntu)) and try again.

Comment: hmmmm... I update my system all the time it just refuse to install ti.

Comment: @Jonthue the same error or something else? Also, do you have any third-part PPAs added to the software sources?

Answer (score 0):

If you get this kind of problems, the first thing to do is to run these two commands

> sudo apt-get update

followed by

> sudo apt-get upgrade

I sometimes also run

> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Then try installing

Comment: I tried and then it failed